# How to find all available fonts on OSX using the default shell

Tags: bash, macos, fonts, applescript, extendscript

I'm trying to write a script for Adobe After Effects using extendscript (a proprietary ECMAScript dialect, but mostly ≈ javascript). I can use an [inbuilt command](http://docs.aenhancers.com/general/system/#system-callsystem) `system.callSystem()` to execute a command using the default(?) shell, but I can't find a bash one liner, or an AppleScript command I can use to list the available fonts.

Is there a way of getting all the fonts on the command line in OSX?

Comment: try this: `atsutil fonts -list`. It seems to output two lists — system fonts and system font families — so you'll have to massage the output.

Comment: I am no expert but I wonder if there might be a difference between *installed* fonts that applications are aware of and can use, versus files that happen to contain fonts and exist in the filesystem but applications don't know about... just a thought.

Comment: @MarkSetchell good point. I was thinking that the OS would be aware of the installed fonts so there would be some way of querying what's installed. I'm only interested in fonts that are available to the application

Comment: It looks like "Font Book" is Applescriptable maybe... https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=41022

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From AppleScript, you can use this ASOC code to get the names of all of the fonts or font families available to the system:

```
use framework "AppKit"
set fontFamilyNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFontFamilies) as list
set fontNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFonts) as list
```

I'm not sure which of those you want, so I included code for both. If you want to access this script from bash, use the `osascript` command:

```
fontFamilyNames=$(osascript << SCPT
    use framework "AppKit"
    set fontFamilyNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFontFamilies) as list
    return fontFamilyNames
SCPT)
```

Comment: What is ASOC please? And where do I put this code to run it please? And how?

Comment: ASOC is just shorthand for AppleScript Objective-C — AppleScript that uses Objective C objects and commands — which is what I wrote. You can use the first script from the Script Editor app, and the second from the command line or a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: AppleScript

```
tell application "Font Book" to set activeFontsList to name of every font family --- whose enabled is true
```

> Note that the `whose enabled is true` filter is commented out because it slows down the query considerably.

### Solution 2: AppleScript & Bash

You can execute the AppleScript above from Bash like that:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Query the list of fonts with AppleScript.
font_list=$(osascript << SCPT
    tell application "Font Book" to set activeFontsList to name of every font family --- whose enabled is true
SCPT)

# Convert the list to column and sort it.
font_list=$(echo $font_list | awk -e 'gsub(", ", "\n")' | sort -f)

# Display the list.
echo -e "$font_list"

# Display the list size.
echo -e "$font_list" | wc -l | xargs printf "\nFont count: %d\n"
```

Same script but one-liner:

```sh
font_list=$(osascript -e 'tell application "Font Book" to set activeFontsList to name of every font family --- whose enabled is true') && font_list=$(echo $font_list | awk -e 'gsub(", ", "\n")' | sort -f) && echo -e "$font_list"
```

### Solution 3: `fc-list`

```sh
fc-list : family | sort -f
fc-list : family | wc -l | xargs printf "\nFont count: %d\n"
```

You will find some examples here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fc-list-command-in-linux-with-examples/.