# Getting an AppleScript Error when Run within Filemaker

Tags: macos, fonts, applescript, filemaker

The AppleScript code below (that returns a list of active fonts) works fine when run from Script Editor, but returns an error when run from within FileMaker. Any ideas how to fix so it can run when called within FileMaker?

**Error Message:**
Can't make {availableFontFamilies of sharedFontManager of NSFontManager} into type string.

```
use framework "AppKit"

tell application "FileMaker Pro"
    set fontFamilyNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFontFamilies) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
    set fontList to every item of fontFamilyNames as string
    set data cell "scriptResult" of table "globals" to fontList
end tell
```

**Supporting Details:**

- "Allow Apple Events" is enabled under the FileMaker Security settings
- My other AppleScripts within Filemaker are running OK
- FileMaker has "Full Disk Access" under MacOS Security Settings
- Versions: FileMaker Pro 19.6.3.302, MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: Not a filemaker user but other than the `set data cell…` line, your script works fine. Aren't 'data cells' an element of 'records' though? Rather than the table? Also, maybe you have to set the 'value of' rather than the cell itself.

Comment: It works fine in Script Editor and populates the field accordingly in FileMaker; it just doesn't work when called within FileMaker. "Data cell" would be the contents of a "field" within a "record" within a "table". In this case, "scriptResult" is a global field in a tabled that is named "globals"

Comment: Thank you Mockman. Part of your comment was helpful in solving... changing "set data cell" to "set cell" when removing the enclosing tell statement worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for any `tell` command. When you run AppleScript from within FileMaker, the entire script is wrapped in a default `tell application "FileMaker Pro"` block. You need to use `tell` only when you want some commands to be executed by **another** application.

You should be able to do simply:

```
use framework "AppKit"

set fontFamilyNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFontFamilies) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set fontList to every item of fontFamilyNames as string
set cell "YourField" of table "YourTable" to fontList
```

---

*(This is assuming that's the best way to get a list of available fonts; I haven't looked into that and I see there are [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57473124/17153010).)*

Comment: thank you! I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working without the tell statement... had originally tried that but get the error. Turns out "set data cell" was causing the issue when run within Filemaker, and should have been just "set cell" to resolve as your code reflects.

Comment: That is strange. AFAIK `set data cell` is the same thing as `set cell`. But  I see I do get an error with `set data cell`  when the `use framework "AppKit"` instruction is present. I am not sure what's the reason for that (and the error is `-1728`, not the error you reported originally).

Comment: Yeah, I gave the error code based on the code that I had posted, which was with the tell statement, since that at least had worked with Script Editor. As you suggested, I think it may have to do with the AppKit. I have other scripts that use "set data cell" vs "set cell" that worked fine. In any case, though I don't understand the why, at least it works now... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... had to move the tell statement further down. Changed "FileMaker Pro" to "current application" as well to simplify.

```
use framework "AppKit"

set fontFamilyNames to (current application's NSFontManager's sharedFontManager's availableFontFamilies) as list
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to return
set fontList to every item of fontFamilyNames as string

tell current application
    set data cell "scriptResult" of table "globals" to fontList
end tell
```

Comment: That makes very little sense. When you run AppleScript from within FileMaker, you are already in a `tell application "FileMaker Pro"` context.

Comment: The error in the initial script is that it is wrong to look for the **current application's NSFontManager** inside the tell application "FileMaker Pro" block. This is the same as asking for **current application's current application** (which is FileMaker Pro when running a script from it). I can't verify, but if you replace **current application's** with **its** or **it's**, then the initial script should work.

Comment: @RobertKniazidis it's/its didn't work, but resolved with the suggestions from others. Thank you for the suggestion though.